# SQL Query - Find duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this kind of table on a MySQL server with duplicate entries:

[image]

I would like to build a query that will give me the list of all the transID where there are duplicates entries in Client and/or Name, Phone, Mail. So, in this case the result would be :

[image]

So :TransID1, TransID2, TransID3, TransID5, TransID9,TransID10

I tried several combinations without success.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT.

Comment: @Barmar Plainly, SO is a free coding service

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where (t2.name = t.name or t2.phone = t.phone or t2.mail = t.mail) and
                     t2.transid <> t.transid
             );
```

Comment: You've been faster than me, this is great solution to his problem ! Should be accepted

Comment: @Gosfly . . . I gave everyone else a five minute head start on this one.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Just trying to understand that magic :  We create a temporary table and for each row we check if email or name .. have been already present when transid was different. right ?

Comment: @patalvali . . . For each row, you check if there is a row in the table that matches on name, phone, or email and has a different transaction id.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff ! :-)